# Sharepoint List Questions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list

I have successfully created a list that allows users to add new items to the list.

Can I allow users to attach an image to a list and then when this list is viewed, the image is embedded? - I see i can add a hyperlink but that is too much work/ too complicated for a normal user. Ideally the user should just be able to add an attachment and if possible that attachment should be embedded in the page - i.e for jpg,png the image is directly displayed.

Same question as above except for powerpoint - i.e the user can attach a powerpoint image and it is viewable and embedded directly in the page - is this possible?

Finally when users in our company create say 3000 items in the list and one user may want to send out a link one item only - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your first question:** To insert images that are viewable from the main view, create a multiple line column with rich-text enabled. Then, when creating a new item, a user can use the Insert > Picture > 'From Computer' or 'From Address' function to upload the image. [I would post an screenshot but I only recently joined and don't have a high enough rep.]

**Answer to your second question:** There is no way to upload a PowerPoint file and have it preview like an image. That is slightly unreasonable because that would have to be accomplished by some function opening the pptx file, then grabbing the first slide, converting it to an image, saving it somewhere, and having it render in the list. 
The next best thing would be: A) to have links that would allow you to download the files, or B) links that will open the file in SharePoint (provided your site has Web App features installed). Both of these are achieved just like the image.

A) Upload the file in the same field using the Insert > Upload File feature (NOTE: you need a document library already created to host the files). A link will be inserted that, when clicked on, will allow the user to download the file and view it.

B) The user will have to upload the file to the Document Library (does not matter how), open the file in Sharepoint's PowerPoint Web App, copy the URL, and then use that to insert a link [using Insert > Link > From Address ‡]. This link will then open the file in the PowerPoint Web App thus displaying the content.

‡*My site has the "From SharePoint" functionality disabled so I could not test whether that would be better. If your site has this functionality available, I would recommend testing it.*

**Answer to your third question:** No, there is simply to way to conjoin more than one list item URL together into a single address.

Comment: this is an excellent answer - so i have tested your answers to questions 1 and 2 and it works perfect. Now for answer 3 - i need some way to be able to send out an email link so that when clicked it opens one of the sharepoint list rows i.e row 2345 from my list - if i cant do this then all this list in sharepoint is unfortunely pointless as the whole point is to allow users to people who are emailed to be able to view the status of a particular row very simply. Do you have any other suggestions / alternate ideas?

Comment: i just figured out you can right click on one of the rows and "open in a new tab" - that then gives you an emailable link so i am sorted now. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SharePoint Server, you can use the Sitecolumn (Page Layout Column) called "Rollup Image" to solve your first question. Just add this column to your list

Answer (score 0):

I think this site may be useful for what you are doing:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749924.aspx

Comment: hi, above i say "I see i can add a hyperlink but that is too much work/ too complicated for a normal user. Ideally the user should just be able to add an attachment and if possible that attachment should be embedded in the page - i.e for jpg,png the image is directly displayed." - That weblink you reference follows this process. I However want to be able to add an image or PPTX and it gets embedded in the page